# Video captured from x11grab is not playable in HLS format on Firefox/Safari

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm trying to produce an HLS playlist from a video file.

It's a file captured from a virtual screen with ffmpeg and x11grab module:

```
ffmpeg -y -t 10 -copyts -draw_mouse 0 -framerate 24 -f x11grab -thread_queue_size 1024 -i :0 -f pulse -i default -acodec copy /tmp/test_preprocessed.mkv
```

**But when I'm trying to produce HLS from this file, the output seems not correct, as it doesn't play in Firefox/Safari, but does play in Chrome (using hls.js or https://www.hlsplayer.net/ for example)**

Original file: https://transfer.sh/y1a6Fv/735171b9-42a1-461a-a118-981119bdf74e_preprocessed.mkv

HLS Playlist generated from this file: https://video-staging-bucket.ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/c08584ca-4731-4820-b5c7-71f12955c0b2/stackoverflow/playlist.m3u8

(Works in https://www.hlsplayer.net/ with chrome, doesn't works with Firefox/Safari)

How I'm producing the HLS:

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -t 10 \
  -i 735171b9-42a1-461a-a118-981119bdf74e_preprocessed.mkv \
  -r 24 \
  -filter_complex '[0:v]split=3[v1][v2][v3]; [v1]scale=w=1280:h=720[v1out]; [v2]scale=w=854:h=480[v2out]; [v3]scale=w=640:h=360[v3out]' \
  -map '[v1out]' -c:v:0 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:0 3200k -maxrate:v:0 3200k -minrate:v:0 2500k -bufsize:v:0 3200k -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
  -map '[v2out]' -c:v:1 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:1 1600k -maxrate:v:1 1600k -minrate:v:1 1250k -bufsize:v:1 1600k -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
  -map '[v3out]' -c:v:2 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:2 900k -maxrate:v:2 900k -minrate:v:2 700k -bufsize:v:2 900k -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
  -map a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96k \
  -map a:0 -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 128k \
  -map a:0 -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 128k \
  -f hls \
  -hls_time 4 \
  -hls_playlist_type vod \
  -hls_flags independent_segments \
  -hls_segment_type mpegts \
  -hls_segment_filename 'hls'/stream_%v_data%02d.ts \
  -master_pl_name playlist.m3u8 \
  -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" \
  -t 10 \
  'hls'/stream_%v.m3u8
```

Is there something I missed ? Maybe a standard ? Or maybe problem is related to PTS/DTS of my file ?
Thanks !

Comment: Similar reason as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73125890/9099070 , screengrabbing produces high quality YUV 4:4:4 color format that is not widely supported. It is recommended to convert to YUV 4:2:0 for much better compatibility.

Comment: @tbucher thanks ! using "-profile:v baseline -vf format=yuv420p" to change color format fixed my issue